# How to make many reference from one database?

Tags: java, android, android-room

I use Room database on android

i open the main connection to this database on 
`AsyncTask` on `MainActivity.java`

```
 public AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
            AppDatabase.class, "FilmDatabase").fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();
```

I have another class called `FilmActivity.java`
i want to open connection in `FilmActivity.java`
that reference to my `FilmDatabase` to add some data

How can i do that ?

Comment: I Suggest using MVVM and changing FilmActivity to a fragment. I found the CodeInFlow video series to be the most helpful when learning ROOM. I believe your current approach is going to create memory links. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARpn-1FPNE4&t=261s

Answer (score 0):

Move the database creation code into AppDatabase class.

```
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

private static volatile AppDatabase INSTANCE;

static RoomDatabase getDataBase(Context context) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        synchronized (AppDatabase.class) {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, "FilmDatabase")
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();
            }
        }
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}}
```